# How to disable auto reorganization of layout from orientation change inside webbrowser control without losing orientation detection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, orientation, webbrowser-control

building an app in Windows Phone 8, I'm using an webbrowser control inside a PhoneApplicationPage. I defined the XAML "SupportedOrientations" property of the page as "PortraitOrLandscape" as I need to detect when the device goes into Landscape orientation.

**Although,** I only want to update a few things behind the scenes and don't want my web browser control content's layout to get automatically reorganized visually to fit the new orientation.

**The problem is** if I set the XAML attribute for supported orientations as "Portrait" only, the app can't detect any orientation change at all.

***So my question is:*** how can I disable the auto re-organisation of the visual layout of a web browser control whitout losing the feature of device's orientation detection ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could set the orientation property to Portrait, and use the motion sensor to detect orientation changes.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, but it seems to me at first sight this low level approach must be overkill right? Just to detect if the phone is in landscape mode whitout changing anything..? Thanks.